# Mi base de datos solo registra un solo usuarios

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, mysqli

tengo un problema básico en php...yo tengo una base de datos ya montada con sus respectivos campos y con campo ID que es autoincrementable.
El caso es que cuando yo hago la sentencia para registrar un usuario, si no hay ningún usuario registrado lo registra, pero después de eso ya no me registra ningun otro usuario
El código que tengo puesto es:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "Insert Into $tabla_db1 (nombre, password,email,Sexo, Aula, numAula) Values('$nombre','$password','$email','$sexo','$aula','$departamento')");
```

Ese código me funciona bien la primera vez..pero ya cuando voy a introducir un segundo usuario no funciona.. Y los include de abrir y cerrar conexión respectivamente me funcionan.

PD: Cuando yo borró el usuario registrado y vuelvo a intentar registrar otro..me lo registra con el ID correspondiente a la cantidad de intentos que realice..

Ejemplo: Si intento 4 veces sin éxito..borro el usuario en phpmyadmin..y vuelvo a intentar..se me registra con el ID #5.. Necesito saber por favor, por qué me pasa eso..y si me pueden ayudar a resolverlo
Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Si eso no tira ningun error, entonces capaz no estas actualizando los datos que estas mirando?

Comment: Saludos. Aplica a tu table **Truncate** que no solo borra sino también reinicia el autoincremental. Esto debido al escenario que mencionas de que intentas 4 veces y si borras el siguiente obtiene el ID 5. Ahora bien; te sugiero luego del **INSERT** pruebes obtener el error https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php solo así podrás a atender lo que pasa.